# How to download with wget in Python using variables?

Tags: python, bash, wget

I need to do something like this, but in Python instead of Bash:

```
i=1
while [ $i <= 10 ] ; do
    wget http://somewebsite.net/shared/fshared_$i.7z
    $i = $i + 1
done
```

In Python I tried with the following:

```
import urllib, os
i = 0
while i <= 3:
    os.system('wget http://somewebsite.net/shared/fshared_',i,'.7z')
    i = i + 1
```

But it does not work, the variable is not concatenated correctly (or something similar).
Using Bash code does not work, apparently in Bash can't do something simple like: `i = i + 1`

Could anyone help me with this?

**SOLVED!** :)

Now I have the script both Bash and Python, actually with Python I have several variants.

Thanks to all... thanks a lot ^-^

How do I mark the topic as solved?

Thanks again.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, you accept it. If there is more than one correct answer, accept the one you consider best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
os.system('wget http://somewebsite.net/shared/fshared_%s.7z'%i)
```

use `%s` instead of `,`

Comment: Using Python v2:
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Using Python v3:
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

And I already put before the downlaod line: str(i)

Comment: you forget to remove '+' and ',' stuff

Answer (score 1):

You **can** increment in Bash. You have to do something like:

```
i=3
(( i++ ))
echo $i
```

That last like should print 4. So your script would be:

```
i=1
while [ $i -le 10 ] ; do
    wget http://somewebsite.net/shared/fshared_$i.7z
    (( i++ ))
done
```

Edit: fixed code to use `-le` instead of `<=` since `<=` doesn't work in bash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python without calling out to the shell for each file using [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib#urllib.urlretrieve)

```
import urllib, os

for i in range(4):
    filename = 'fshared_{}.7z'.format(i)
    urllib.urlretrieve('http://somewebsite.net/shared/'+filename, filename)
```

Comment: I had tried before with urllib (i don't like mixing bash and python) but it did not work, but with your code it works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem with the concatenation, you need to use `+` to concatenate instead of `,`, because when you use `,` to concatenate two strings it separate them with a space character between, the same doesn't happen when you use `+` because it "really" concatenate the strings.

E.g.:

```
print('Hello' + 'World' + '!')
print('Hello', 'Stack', 'Overflow!')
```

Output:

```
HelloWorld!
Hello Stack Overflow!
```

Your code would look like this now using `+` instead of `,`:

```
#...
os.system('wget http://somewebsite.net/shared/fshared_' + i + '.7z')
#...                                                    ^   ^
```

[Code pasted on Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/IJBgBQ)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import urllib, os
i = 0
while i <= 3:
    os.system('wget http://somewebsite.net/shared/fshared_%s.7z' % i)
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also specify python to ask you the url to pass to wget

```
import os
path = raw_input("enter the url:")
os.system('wget -r -nd -l1 --no-parent -A mp3 %s'%path)
```

in place of 'mp3' use whatever format you want to download.